# How to stack images with Tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics

I would like to stack several png images as shown below

[image]

How can I do this with Tikz?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ti*k*Z has a predefined 3d coordinate system, which is not orthographic, but more than sufficient to stack some objects in the z direction.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\definecolor{fb}{RGB}{128,158,204}
\definecolor{db}{RGB}{111,141,191}  
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \foreach \Z in {0,0.5,1,1.5}
 {\draw[fill=fb,draw=db] (-2,-2,\Z) rectangle (2,2,\Z);}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

For external images it works the same way. (I made them a bit transparent to show that these are really different images, but you can remove the `opacity=0.8` key.)

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \foreach \X [count=\Z]in {a,b,c,duck}
 {\node[opacity=0.8] at (0,0,\Z/2) {\includegraphics[width=4cm,height=3cm]{example-image-\X}};}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you please tell me where I put my png images? I don't want to draw blue squares but would like to use actual images.

Comment: @random9 This is in the second part of my answer.

Comment: Very nice `example-image-duck` did not know about this one :) !

Comment: @BambOo It needs to be stressed that there is no pineapple on the pizza. ;-)

Comment: That's a big  **NO** against the so-called hawaian pizza :)

Comment: @BambOo pineapple on a pizza is a bit like an italic differential d: wrong but some people like it. ;-)

Comment: Anywhere else, this would be a far-fetched analogy, but I agree ^^

Comment: Can you please explain what `(0,0,\Z/2)` stands for? I don't see how every image is shifted along the x and y axis by a certain amount.

Comment: @random9 Yes, Ti*k*Z has a unit vector in the z direction, which is `(-1/(2*sqrt(2)),-1/(2*sqrt(2)))` in screen coordinates. You can verify this by adding `\makeatletter
\pgfmathsetmacro{\pft}{1cm/(2*sqrt(2))}
\typeout{e_z=(\the\pgf@zx,\the\pgf@zy)=(-\pft,-\pft)}
\makeatother` to the code. That is, if you supply a third component to the coordinate, you will add the component times this unit vector.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat Sorry, I still don't see how the unit vector shifts the image? Can I do the translation also using only the x and y coordinate?

Comment: @random9 It means that, say, the point `(1,1,0)` gets mapped to the screen coordinate `(1cm,1cm)`, and the point `(1,1,1)` will get mapped to `((1-1/(2*sqrt(2)))*1cm, (1-1/(2*sqrt(2)))*1cm)`, which is shifted to the down left compared to the first point.